# Override scaffolding.less for body tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I've been working on a webpage and I've just added bootstrap to it, however when I bootstrap to the site  it has overridden the background colour of the body, I have attached the fiddle below. I would like my site to look like the first image, however currently it looks like the second image.

does anyone know the best way to override this and have my original colour background like in the first image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style after you have included bootstrap.min.css file.

like your style.css file-

```
body {
        background-color: #161A25;
        margin:0;
    }
    #logo {
        position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
    h9
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:25rem;
    top:2.5rem;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    h6
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:15rem;
    top:2.5rem;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    h7
    {
      color: #32CE87;
        position:absolute;
    right:2rem;
    top:1.5rem;
        font-size: 7px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    h8
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:2rem;
    top:1.5rem;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
       color: #32CE87;
    }

    .footer {
       position: fixed;

       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
        height:110px;
       background-color: #2A3046;
       color: white;


    }

    img.logo {
       height: 80px;
         left:3em;
        position: relative

    }
    img.logo1 {
       height: 40px;
        left:3em;

        bottom:2rem;
        position:absolute;
    }



    .my-button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px;
        background: #32CE87;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        width: 100px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .my-button:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #c1e1e0;
    }
    .center-bottom {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 12rem;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    img.arrow {
        max-height: 40px;
    }

    .row {
        background-color: white;
        max-width:100%;
       height: 150px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;;

        margin-top: 0.1rem;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;

    }
    .box1 {
        background-color: white;
        max-width:100%;
        height:150px;
        padding-bottom:50px;

        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
         border-radius: 5px;


    }
    p {
        font-size:7px;
        width:380px;
        position: absolute;
        right:12em;
        text-align: left;
        bottom: 1.5rem;

    }
    img.laptop { 

        height: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        right: 0px;


        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
    }
    div.bottomtext {
        position: relative;
         left:0px;
        right: 0px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        text-align: center;
     width:800px;
        top:4rem;
        font-size: 0.6rem;


    }

    img.textimage
    {
        height:20px;
        left:8rem;
        position: absolute;
         font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    .images {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:200px;
    }
    #content {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        top: 90px;
        height: auto;
        max-width: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x:auto;
        word-wrap:normal;
        white-space:nowrap;
        height: 50px;
    }

    img.column {
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    img.row
    {height:60px;

    }
    h9:hover {
          color: #32CE87;
    }
    h6:hover {
          color: #32CE87;

    }
    p:hover {
          color: #32CE87;

    }
    h7:hover {
          color: white;

    }
    h8:hover {
          color: white;

    }
     .pt-inner-wrap {
        color: #ecf0f1;
        padding: 15px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        border-right: 3px solid #d4d4d4;   
        }

    div.container {

    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
```

After that include this.. style.css file after you included bootstrap.min.css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>   

<body>
    <img src="Logo-Trans.png" class="logo" >

    <div class="toptext"> 
    <h9> GET A QUOTE</h9>
    <h6> RETRIEVE A QUOTE</h6>
    <h7>NEED HELP OR ADVICE?CALL US <br style>  </h7>
        <h8> 0800 0481804</h8>
        </div>



<img src="nav.png" class="column"> 






<div class="container">

  <div class="row">


<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x"></i>
    <h4 class="pt-title">Mobile &amp Smartphone</h4>
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10000.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x"></i>
    <h4 class="pt-title">Ipad's &amp Tablets</h4>
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10000.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" >
    <div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x"></i>
    <h4 class="pt-title">Laptops &amp Macs</h4>
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="10000.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6 class="pt-title">How many would you like to insure</h6>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>          

 <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




      <div class="box1"> 


<div> <img src="laptop.png" class="laptop"> </div>


<div class="bottomtext">Please enter a figure for the number of individual laptops/macbooks that you would like to insure in each price range. <br> Where you dont want cover with a particular price range, please leave bank.</div>
    </div> 





    <div class="footer">

       <div class="center-bottom">

<a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Back</a>
<a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Next</a>

</div>

  <p> © Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd 2016 All rights reserved. Mobiru is a trading style of Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd which is authorised and regulated by the Financial Conduct Authority. Our registered office is Midland House, 2 Poole Road, Bournemouth, Dorset BH2 5QY and we are registered in England under company number 08810662. Should you have cause to complain, and you are not satisfied with our response to your complaint, you may be able to refer it to the Financial Ombudsman Service, which can be contacted as follows: The Financial Ombudsman Service Exchange Tower, London, E14 9SR | Tel: 0800 023 4567 or 0300 123 9 123 | www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk </p>
          <img src="Logo-Trans.png" class="logo1">
</div>


    </body>





</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vikash,  Thanks for the response! I have just tried to implement this and it doesnt work. heres the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ym3gphqr/

Comment: [harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7806114/harry) It is not showing in jsfiddle, because it is not properly included in jsfiddle website. In my suggestion, Please try it on your system. You can check in jsfiddle, like when you click on style.css, it shows Error 404

Comment: Ah my bad, Ill try to add a new screenshot of how it looks with the new code you sent me :)

Comment: Ive changed the image to what I currently have with your code updates, its made my page not fit in the desktop and I have to view it in 67% to see the whole page and so I could fit it in the image, what do you suggest from here?

Comment: Check this fiddle.. You might get some idea . 
 What I am trying to Say. https://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/4a9avbct/1/  Other images will also start to display, when you give the correct path

Comment: Nice converstaion, Be in touch by ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162429/discussion-between-harry-and-vikash-777).